# Need to add info/tooltip points on streamgraph in R

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, stream-graph

I have a streamgraph similar to this,

```
library(dplyr) 
library(babynames) 
library(streamgraph)

babynames %>%   
filter(grepl("^Kr", name)) %>%   
group_by(year, name)
%>%   tally(wt=n) -> baby_names

head(baby_names) 

streamgraph(baby_names, "name", "nn", "year")
```

URL: http://hrbrmstr.github.io/streamgraph/

How can I add a custom tooltip with text coming from other source (e.g., from an additional column of the data frame)